# How to declare a List in Drools rule

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, rule

I've got a simple object construction. The class `ContextDroolsObject` has a property of type `Map` called `objects`. Inside that map there's a key `"imageThemes"` with an `ArrayList` and this rule here never matches:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import com.my.ContextDroolsObject;

dialect 'java'


rule 'Soccer Image Theme'
    salience 100
    when
        s : ContextDroolsObject()
        objectsm : Map() from s.objects
         imageThemesList : ArrayList() from outputsm.imageThemes
    then
System.out.println("-----------------------soccer");
    end
```

I've also tried with List() with same result.

¿How to match the list declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can rewrite your rule in this way:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import com.my.ContextDroolsObject;

dialect 'java'


rule 'Soccer Image Theme'
salience 100
when
    s : ContextDroolsObject( imageThemesList : objects#Map.get("imageThemes") )
then
    System.out.println("-----------------------soccer");
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a hierarchical structure for fact objects is ver frequently a design flaw. You may not be able to reason conveniently over the list elements.

Anyway, this is the way to extract the list within the map from the ContextDroolsObject.

```
rule 'Soccer Image Theme'
  salience 100
when
  s: ContextDroolsObject() 
  imageThemesList: ArrayList() from s.getObjects().get( "imageThemes" )
then
  System.out.println("-----------------------soccer");
end
```

Comment: I've just tried, it did not work. I commented about the flaw design the first day I found this because I've worked with other rule engines before but... there's a *smarter* guy as an architect down here...